# Shared folder on uBuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, shared-folders

I'm running Windows 8.1 as the host and uBuntu 14.04 LTS as the guest OS. Oracle VirtualBox 4.3.18 is in use.

I have two guest VMs, one Windows XP and the other uBuntu 14.04 LTS. I believe I've installed the Guest Additions into both VMs. I've configured the Shared Folders exactly the same for both guest OS.

[image: VirtuaBox shared folder]

In Windows XP this appears as "E:\", but I cannot see the shared folder in uBuntu using the file explorer. Is there something extra I need to do? BTW, "V:\VMs" is the drive letter and folder for the external SSD I use to host the VMs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to mount it:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf VMs ~/host
```

Comment: Is this a filesystem/mount option you'd find on a typical linux system or do you need some package to enable this?

Comment: I think the vboxfs type (and the mount.vboxfs command) comes with the guest addtions. I seem to remember that auto mount doesn't work with linux so you have to actually mount the share.

Comment: This only works for your current session. It does not establish permanent mounting.